# Is it possible to use new as a method name in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm jealous of Ruby with their use of "new" as a method. Is it possible to achieve this in PHP 5.3 with the use of namespaces?

```
class Foo
{
     public function new()
     {
         echo 'Hello';
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Like already pointed out elsewhere, `new` is a reserved keyword. Trying to use it as a method name will result in a Parse error: "syntax error, unexpected `T_NEW`, expecting `T_STRING`". Namespaces will not help, because the `new` keyword applies to any namespace. The only way around this would be by means of a virtual method, e.g.

```
/**
 * @method String new new($args) returns $args
 */
class Foo
{
     protected function _new($args)
     {
         return $args;
     }
     public function __call($method, $args)
     {
         if($method === 'new') {
             return call_user_func_array(array($this, '_new'), $args);
         } else {
             throw new LogicException('Unknown method');
         }
     }
}
$foo = new Foo;
echo $foo->new('hello'); // return hello
echo $foo->boo();        // throws Exception
```

But I would discourage this. All magic methods are slower than direct invocation of methods and if the simple rule is there may be no method name `new`, then just be it. Use a synonym.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I love new though. Ah. Maybe I'll use create instead.

Answer (score 5):

as you can see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php), "new" is on the list of the reserved words, so you cannot use it to name a method.

> You cannot use any of the following words as constants, class names, function or method names

Answer (score 3):

Well the short answer to that appears to be **no**, as it is a [reserved keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).

It would be nice to have available in classes like that, but reserved words are important for a reason.  People tend to use other synonyms instead: create, new, getInstance() [usually static usage], etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as of PHP7. But only within classees, interfaces and traits.

> Globally reserved words as property, constant, and method names within classes, interfaces, and traits are now allowed. ...

-- http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.other-changes.php#migration70.other-changes.loosening-reserved-words

Comment: Yes, 'new' can be a method name in the classes. A typical use case is in Symfony 4,  "php bin/console make:crud" will create a 'new' method in a controller class. But some IDEs such as Netbeans will report a syntax error.