# Codeigniter function named 'new'

Tags: php, codeigniter, keyword, reserved-words

Why can't you name a Codeigniter function "new" in a controller (and possibly elsewhere)?

```
public function new()
{
    $this->load->view('posts/new');
}
```

Results in error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Comment: Possible [duplication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291574/is-it-possible-to-use-new-as-a-method-name-in-php-5-3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't only do that in `Codeigniter`, but in all PHP that you write it should `throw` an error. `new` is a reserved word in `PHP`. You can find out more about reserved words in `PHP` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).

People generally try to overcome this by placing a an underscore (`_`) before the function name.

```
function _new() 
{
    echo "Hello!";
}
```

Comment: I would say ppl generally put `_` in front of private methods.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Ah, I guess it is opinionated/personal preference? I've really seen it done in the scenario I've provided, but then again either of us could be right or even both.

Comment: Actually I think in CI it treats them as not accessible when using `_`, or it might be my Custom Router I cant remember If I set it up that way or if it is a part of CI.  Updated my answer CI considers methods starting with underline private

Comment: Please note I am trying to be mean, I use CI.  And remembered that little quirk, so I just wanted the OP to know about it.  As for personal preference, it's part of the Zend's ( and other ) PHP coding standards.  http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html, that said It is a matter of personal preference, but also a bit deeper then that.

Answer (score 2):

For those that say you can't do it I say I can.  Any takers?

```
$test = new Test();
$test->new();

class test{

    public function __call($method, $args){
        if( $method == 'new' ){
            echo 'Hello World';
        }else{
            trigger_error('Call to undefined method '.__CLASS__.'::'.$method,E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Magic!

Although I should note that Codeigniter's Router class probably wont find the method defined this way.  So it's not really a solution for that.  But as others mentioned its a keyword ( or construct ) in the PHP language itself.

Personally I can sort of understand restricting new for object use, but `empty()` always makes me a bit mad.

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'empty' (T_EMPTY), expecting identifier (T_STRING)`

That one they should really fix, along with include, require etc..  Totally different context.

**UPDATE FOR CI SCOPE**

From https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html

**Private Functions**

> In some cases you may want certain functions hidden from public
>   access. To make a function private, simply add an underscore as the
>   name prefix and it will not be served via a URL request. For example,
>   if you were to have a function.

```
private function _utility()
{
   // some code
}
```

> Trying to access it via the URL, like this, will not work:

```
example.com/index.php/blog/_utility/
```

I only mention this because the OP states using CI

Comment: Nice workaround.  I was so stuck in the Codeigniter way, I didn't even think about new being used in the traditional OOP sense.

Comment: @pmm4654 - did you see my note about CI scoping

Comment: @artisticphoenix Just saw!  I use the underscore for private functions quite often in codeigniter (a lot of for partial views or db manipulation)

Comment: @pmm4654 - it's an OK feature, I have mixed feelings about manipulating the scope of things with such schematics.   I just like CI because it's pretty straight forward and easy to modify the core functionality.  However, i don't think they will be updating it much in the future.

Comment: just a note - apparently zend is going to remove this and they are recommending it not be used. i use codeigniter and have used the underscore mainly to avoid having to type out 'private' but am going to change. finally codeigniter is under very active development - there are ongoing releases for CI3 and the next CI4 is active.

Answer (score 1):

`new` is a reserved keyword in PHP.

Read more about it in the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php).

[PHP keywords](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php)